# Angular two way binding not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs and I want to establish a connection to my server and dynamically show the result to user. so far I've tried:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('socketsController', function($scope) {

  $scope.socket = {
    client: null,
    stomp: null
  };

  $scope.reconnect = function() {
    setTimeout($scope.initSockets, 10000);
  };

  $scope.notify = function(message) {
    $scope.result = message.body;
  };

  $scope.initSockets = function() {
    $scope.socket.client = new SockJS('/resources');
    $scope.socket.stomp = Stomp.over($scope.socket.client);
    $scope.socket.stomp.connect({}, function() {
      $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe('/user/topic/messages', $scope.notify);
    });
    $scope.socket.client.onclose = $scope.reconnect;
  };
  $scope.initSockets();
});
```

But when I use `{{result}}` nothing appears.

> UPDATE
>   The server response is totally right with `console.log(message.body)`.

Comment: any error in browser devtools?

Comment: No, nothing appears

Comment: are you resetting the $scope.result any where in the code ?

Comment: I don't really understand how your code works, but you didn't provide any parameter when you called `$scope.notify`.

Comment: try like this $scope.notify = function(message){$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.result = message.body})};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the callback is not taking the scope properly. Try call $scope.$apply(); after you attach the message.body to result :

```
$scope.notify = function(message) {
    $scope.result = message.body;
    $scope.$apply();
  };
```

$scope.$apply() triggers an angular digest cycle whcih will update all the bindings..

Comment: Thanks. very helpful.

Comment: my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 1):

Call it inside a timeout function but inject $timeout first it will call the digest cycle and update the value.

```
$timeout(function(){
$scope.result = message.body;});
```